# How to read JSON into a JObject when the string contains double quotes ?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a piece of JSON that I want to get into a string for C# to use. The problem is when I escape all the double quotes it seems no longer valid. For example:

```
 string jsonString = " {[ {    \"FieldId\": \"Fields.364\",    \"FieldName\": \"LoanNo\",    \"Precision\": \"0\"  } ,  {    \"FieldId\": \"Fields.4002\",    \"FieldName\": \"LastNameB\"  } ]}";
        JObject jsettings = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
```

Is there a easier way to get a string of JSON into a C# JObject?

Comment: those escapes are there only to make it a valid string for C#. the "compiled" string will NOT contain the escapes.

Comment: The double quotes aren't the problem - `"{ [" ` isn't the beginning of any valid JSON string. You have the beginning of an object (`{`), so the next thing we see should be a key (`\"foo\"`); instead you have the beginning of an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not *actually* escaping any of the double quotes, as far as the JSON is concerned - the string doesn't contain any backslashes. You can confirm that with `Console.WriteLine(jsonString);`.

The problem is that you've currently got an array directly inside an object - that's not valid JSON.

If you change it so that the array is a *property*, it's fine:

```
string jsonString = " { \"foo\":[ { /* rest as before */ } ] }";
```

That ended up as JSON of:

```
{
  "foo": [
    {
      "FieldId": "Fields.364",
      "FieldName": "LoanNo",
      "Precision": "0"
    },
    {
      "FieldId": "Fields.4002",
      "FieldName": "LastNameB"
    }
  ]
}
```

(Just using `Console.WriteLine(jsettings);` after the code you'd posted.)

Comment: Seems to work .. I guess my problem was  I was just taking the starting part of the huge string and therefore missed the correct closure

Comment: What about a back slash?  If I escape it (two backslashes) the json won't parse  {      "FieldId": "Fields.2180",      "FieldName": "Marksman \ Costco"    },

Comment: @punkouter: You need *four* backslashes in the string literal in C# - you want a string with two backslashes in (for JSON) and you have to escape each of those too, for the string literal. Or use a verbatim string literal. Or (simpler) just load the text from a file, for testing purposes - then C# literal syntax *can't* get in the way.